# MS Excel VBA Forms - Hide Control

Tags: vba, excel

I am using MS Excel VBA forms.

On my form, there is a drop down list and based on the selection changed in dropdown, I want to hide and show controls.

I am able to hide the control by setting visible to true on control, but they still occupy space on the form.

Is there any way to collapse control while hiding controls on VBA forms (somewhat similar to WPF visibility = collapse)

Do let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: You could have a look at this to see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100310/self-adjusting-userform-size

Comment: What I have done in the past is manipulate the "TOP"/"LEFT"/"HEIGHT" parameters based on conditions x/y/z. I have also layered things on top of one another with visible settings so that they occupy the same area but you can alternate between them.